# SQL Table: Primary key ID not auto incrementing

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I automatically generated this file with Visual Studio:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [Id]                     INT           NOT NULL,
    [name]                   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [surname]                VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [dni]                    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [phone]                  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [gender]                 BIT           NOT NULL,
    [email]                  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [inscriptionDate]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [address]                VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [postalCode]             VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [city]                   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [province]               VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [photo]                  IMAGE         NULL,
    [medicalHistory]         VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [preferredMedicalCenter] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [contactPersonName]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [contactPersonPhone]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

However the primary key `ID` is not auto-incremented, while I thought it will do it.

Any hint?

Comment: Strange format for mysql ... seem sqlserver ..

Comment: Use **Identity** `[ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just auto increment the  `[Id]` field with `IDENTITY(1,1)`:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
        [Id]                     INT           IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [name]                   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [surname]                VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [dni]                    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [phone]                  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [gender]                 BIT           NOT NULL,
        [email]                  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [inscriptionDate]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [address]                VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [postalCode]             VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [city]                   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [province]               VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [photo]                  IMAGE         NULL,
        [medicalHistory]         VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
        [preferredMedicalCenter] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
        [contactPersonName]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [contactPersonPhone]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I´ve got the feeling your option will work, but I am not being able to test it. Every single time I refresh the SQL code, it remains the same as it was! I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231436/visual-studio-ignoring-sql-changes As soon as I am able to test this, I will mark your solution as correct if it works. Thanks again man

Comment: it works well as i have tested this in the *SQL Server Management Studio*.  Checking the other question of yours.

Comment: Thanks buddy, how do you update the SQL code? Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: @stackman I'm not using the **SQL Server Express** that comes along with Visual Studio, instead I am using the **SQL Server Management Studio** *(SSMS in short)*

Comment: Thanks, mate. Do you just hit the "Update" button? I am using SQL Server Data Tools 2015

Comment: are you using *Visual Studio 2015* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111977/discussion-between-rakitic-and-stack-man).