# Visual Studio ignoring SQL changes in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am writing a C# app in Visual Studio.

However, I am facing a weird problem which is driving me mad:

For some reason, every single time I change the SQL code of a Table, and hit `Update`, it says `Update was correct`, but, after executing the program and add some registers, the **SQL code was the same as it used to be**.

I´ve been trying to search other answers without success. Any hint?

Comment: What kind of application is this? A WinForms/WPF or a WEB one? Do you use the DataDirectory substitution string in your connection string?

Comment: Can you post the code? It's hard to understand your problem from your question. Where are you updating the sql?

Comment: just give this a try @stackman , don't know if it might work: Hit your **VS** and *Run as Admin* and see if you are able to update your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using typed  datasets then you have to manually update them if you update your schema.

Comment: How can I do that buddy?

Comment: Return to the dataset where iy was created and rerun the sql query or update it accordingly